# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (26) when using optimize.curve

Tags: curve-fitting

I'm trying to get a best fit line to some data my script generates.  This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
.
.
.
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c
popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(func, numgelt, turnsG)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (26)
```

I have checked and the two arrays (numgelt and turnsG) are definitely the same size.  I've also ensured that the entries are float.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem until I realized I had been using lists instead of Numpy arrays. Converting to arrays fixed it for me.

Comment: To guess why this might be the right answer: I believe there may be some internal addition between iterables which, in the case of lists, is treated as concatenation rather than element-by-element addition. Based on the error message, I don't think the error is discovered immediately, but this is an obvious difference between lists and arrays.

Comment: My goodness, I can't believe such a simple fix would result in such an obscure error!  Thanks for posting!!!

Comment: I had the same problem with `numpy.leastsq( )`, and wrapping my x/y list arguments AND initial parameters in `np.array(  )` solved the problem.  Perhaps it's multiplying the initial parameters by the x/y arrays, so if one of those is a list (with dimensions `0`) while the other is an array, then you get this dimensions-don't-match error.  WOuld have been nice if numpy just said "This isn't an array, dimensions=0!" or something!

Answer (score -1):

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (26)
```

implies that first of your arrays is of length 0. From your post it is most obviously the case and the error provoking ValueError.