# scipy curve fit failing to fit Lorentzian

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am attempting to use the curve_fit function in scipy to fit a series of Lorentzian curves to a series of peaks.
Currently the code relevant to my problem is:

```
def fit_a_Lorentzian_peak(wavenumber_position,amplitude,peak_center,linewidth):
    x =  ( wavenumber_position - peak_center)/ (linewidth/2.0)     
    return amplitude/( 1.0 + x**2)


Xdata, Ydata= numpy.loadtxt(....) 
Xdata= numpy.array(Xdata) 
Ydata= numpy.array(Ydata)

initialGuess = [Ydata[maximum_point_index], Xdata[maximum_point_index], 2.0] 

fitting_parameters, covarance_matrix_of_fitting_parameters  = curve_fit(fit_a_Lorentzian_peak, Xdata[data_range_to_fit_to_lower:data_range_to_fit_to_upper],Ydata[data_range_to_fit_to_lower:data_range_to_fit_to_upper],p0=initialGuess)
```

I have omitted the code that obtain the data_range_to_fit_to_lower:data_range_to_fit_to_upper as it is irrelevant to the error that Is occurring.

The error that is occurring is as follows:

```
 File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 515, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 354, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 17, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "D:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 427, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "D:\DropBox\Dropbox\PhD\Time resolved spectroscopy data\utility\transmission_plotting_and_analysis_V_09.py", line 38, in fit_a_Lorentzian_peak
    x =  ( wavenumber_position - peak_center)/ (linewidth/2.0)     
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (73757) (10332)
```

Now I know exactly what the problem is here, but I have absolutely no idea why it is occurring or how to fix it. Why is curve_fit feeding parameters and independent variable arrays of different sizes to my fitting function?

Now i have identified others having what at first appears to be this same problem:
[ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (26) when using optimize.curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220425/valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-0-26-when-u)

However, I have added in the lines where i explicitly ensure that my Xdata and Ydata are both numpy arrays, so this cannot be the same problem.

Has anyone here come across this problem before and been able to solve it?
And if so, how?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, my initialGuess array was wrong.
Was accidentally feeding in maximum_point_index as an array of integers instead of an integer, thus giving many more initial parameter estimates than parameters.