# Value error in optimize.curve_fit not solved by inputing numpy arrays

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some data to a function using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, but keep getting a value error, similar to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220425/valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes-0-26-when-u), but making all the inputs into numpy arrays as recommended in the comments does not seem to fix my problem.

Here is my basic code:

```
def RamanHamiltonian(k, omega, delta, epsilon):
    H = np.array([[(k+2.0)**2.0 - delta, omega/2.0, 0.0],
                  [omega/2.0, k**2.0-epsilon,omega/2.0],
                  [0.0,omega/2.0,(k-2.0)**2.0 + delta]])
    return H

def propagateHamiltonianTest(t, omega, delta, epsilon):  
    k = 0.0
    psi0 = np.array([0+1j*0.0, 1.0+1j*0.0, 0.0+1j*0.0])
    H = RamanHamiltonian(k, omega, delta ,epsilon)
    Energy, V = LA.eig(H)

    V = V + 1j*0.0
    Vinv = np.conjugate(np.transpose(V))

    U = np.diag(np.exp(-1j*np.array(Energy)*t))
    a  =np.dot(Vinv,psi0)
    b = np.dot(U,a)
    psi = np.dot(V,b)
    pop0 = np.absolute(psi[0])**2.0

    return pop0

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(propagateHamiltonianTest,
                               np.array(tRecoils), 
                               np.array(frac0), 
                               p0=(3.0,0.05,0.03))
```

And here are the values for `tRecoils` and `frac0`, both of them length 24 arrays:

```
tRecoils = array([ 2.88597836,  1.15439135,  1.73158702,  2.19334356,  0.23087827,
    2.07790442,  0.11543913,  1.50070875,  2.77053923,  1.61614788,
    1.03895221,  2.42422183,  0.92351308,  0.80807394,  0.3463174 ,
    0.57719567,  2.6551001 ,  0.46175654,  1.84702615,  1.38526961,
    2.53966096,  0.69263481,  2.30878269,  1.96246529])
frac0 = array([ 0.15761062,  0.02044625,  0.17275937,  0.02236243,  0.07388558,
    0.00967176,  0.01886309,  0.20412516,  0.21667489,  0.21783697,
    0.00173812,  0.14038657,  0.03145599,  0.08644404,  0.13153078,
    0.18794377,  0.2139092 ,  0.17141201,  0.13021916,  0.12671806,
    0.21090369,  0.1611094 ,  0.08732627,  0.05764911])
```

I am getting this error:

> U = np.diag(np.exp(-1j*np.array(Energy)*t))
>
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3)
>   (24)

So for some reason curve_fit reads in the entire `tRecoil` array instead of doing it element-wise, and I can't seem to remedy this by changing the input formats.

Comment: How is `LA` defined (in the line `Energy, V = LA.eig(H)`)?

Comment: `numpy.linalg`, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there is an ambiguity in how your function `propagateHamiltonianTest` can be evaluated. It can either be applied to a single value of `t` (which is how you are thinking of it), or it can be applied to the whole array, in which case numpy passes the whole array into the argument `t` and attempts to vectorise.

In fact, when I tested your function on a single element of your array `tRecoil[0]` for example, it works, but when you try it on the whole array, it fails with the same error. So the problem is nothing to do with `curve_fit`. If yo can get your function to take the whole array in, and return an array out, then it should work with `curve_fit`.

To do this, I had to use a bit of a hacky trick, using `scipy.linalg.block_diag`. This allows us to create a larger block diagonal matrix, which basically has each of the 3x3 matrices that result from each time step along the diagonal.

A modified version of your `propagateHamiltonianTest` function is below with comments. I've tested it and it should work.

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def propagateHamiltonianTest(t, omega, delta, epsilon):  
    k = 0.0
    psi0 = np.array([0+1j*0.0, 1.0+1j*0.0, 0.0+1j*0.0])
    H = RamanHamiltonian(k, omega, delta ,epsilon)
    Energy, V = LA.eig(H)

    V = V + 1j*0.0
    Vinv = np.conjugate(np.transpose(V))

    # np.outer(t, Energy).flatten() creates a matrix for all t
    U = np.diag(np.exp(-1j*np.outer(t, Energy).flatten()))  
    a = np.dot(Vinv, psi0)
    # This repeats a so that the shape is consitent with U
    aa = block_diag(*([a]*t.size))                          
    # Have to add the transpose to make shapes match 
    b = np.dot(U, aa.T)                                     
    # Same block diagonal trick for eigenvector matrix
    VV = block_diag(*([V]*t.size))                          
    psi = np.dot(VV, b)
    pop0 = np.absolute(psi)**2.0                       
    # Since you want the first value, need to take every 3rd row 
    # and extract the values you want from the diagonal
    return np.diag(pop0[::3])
```

Output:

```
print('popt: ', popt, '\n\npcov: ', pcov)

popt:  [ 2.59126808 -0.13125704  0.52597681] 

pcov:  [[ 0.00114962  0.00072806 -0.0005113 ]
        [ 0.00072806  0.00076575 -0.00020831]
        [-0.0005113  -0.00020831  0.00063511]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly. However, I think I'm just a little confused about how python assigns data types. A very simple function will recreate the same error: def test(t, a):
    b=np.array([a,a,a])
    c=t*b
    return c[0], but when I set b=a, for example, and not an array, python knows that t should be a float and not an array. This seems like a pretty basic problem. Is there any way to explicitly define the data type of function inputs?

Comment: As far as I  know, there isn't a way to specify types explicitly in functions. To be honest, I don't know how numpy does it. All I can suggest is to be very clear in your own mind what the types you are passing. If you are working with numpy arrays, then bear in mind that, for example, if you try to multiply two arrays they must be of the same shape, as numpy will try and do the multiplication elementwise. Not sure if this helps.